# How do I convert this Ajax function (in prototype) to a jquery one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

Can anyone please help me to translate this function in prototype to the equivalent in jQuery

```
function updateNewsletter(){                  
    if ($('newsletter_dump')){
        $('newsletter_dump').remove();
    }
    newsletterParam = $('newsletter_form').serialize(true);
    newsletterParam.template_output = 'box/plugin_newsletter';

    new Ajax.Updater('newsletter_form_holder', 'index.php', {
        parameters: newsletterParam,
        evalScripts: true
    });
}
```

Thanks is advance.

I tried this code but not working. I keep getting an object error

```
function updateNewsletter(){                  
    if ($('#newsletter_dump')){
        $('#newsletter_dump').remove();
    }
    newsletterParam = $('#newsletter_form').serialize(true);
    newsletterParam.template_output = 'box/plugin_newsletter';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {"newsletterParam" : "newsletter_form_holder"},
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem may come from `newsletterParam.template_output = 'box/plugin_newsletter';` Any idea on how to add another form element to the serialised one in jQuery?
Thanks

Comment: Well, did you try anything?

Comment: No I didn't as I am not confortable with these libraries.

Comment: jQuery provides nice [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for using it's library/functions. Take a look at it and identify what you don't understand.

Comment: Is there any quick suggestion please ?

Comment: Don't be lazy and RTFM, you might learn a useful thing or two.

Comment: I am using jQuery with a script and needed to translate this function and not use prototype to avoid conflict. Thanks

Comment: Well, I assume that people downvoted you because you didn't provide the custom code (your attempt code) that is posted now, so I upvoted you. I think the object error is caused by this: ``newsletterParam.template_output``. That's probably a prototype thing, though I'm not sure whatsoever.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :-) Yes it is a prototype stuff. I couldn't find a way to translate it to  jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Prototype's serialize function, jQuery's serialize function returns a string only. Your error is due to the fact that you are using `newsletterParam` as an object rather than a string. So to fix the problem just append the `template_output` parameter as a string:

```
newsletterParam = $('newsletter_form').serialize();
newsletterParam += '&template_output=box/plugin_newsletter';
```

Also, the data setting in your ajax call should be

```
data: newsletterParam,
```